# Python - Looping through list and modifying variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I have a small script that I need help with.  Basically it is a script that logins to Cisco switch and suggests what vlan is available to use.  For example, if user wants to add vlan 10.  The script will look at vlan table and determine if vlan 10 is available, if it is then it succeeds.  If not, the first iteration it will append 1 to 10 and will make it 101.  It then goes through and checks if 101 is available, and if it is also already in use, this time it increments by 1 so 101 will become 102, 103 and so on until it has a vlan thats not in use (in the list).

My issue is I am getting this"
10, 101, 1012, 10123, and so on ..

It should be like this:
10, 101, 102, 103, and so on ...

I hard coded some variables to make the script simple, please take a look:

```
# Hard coded vlan and vlan_list for testing     
vlan_list = ["1","11", "10", "20", "30", "101", "102", "103", "1011", "1012", "10123", "10111"]
vlan = "10"
# Print what first vlan user has chosen       
print "Vlan is: " + vlan
# If vlan is already in list, append 1. Example: if vlan 10 is already in list, the new vlan would be 101.
#and if 101 is also in vlan_lits, this time increment the newly added 1 like, 102, 103 and so on until it finds a # thats not in vlan_list     
initial = 0
while vlan in vlan_list:
    print "Vlan " + vlan + " is already in use, creating new vlan ..."
    initial = initial + 1
    str_initial = str(initial)
    vlan = vlan  + str_initial  
    print "Vlan chosen is: " + vlan

print "Vlan " + vlan + " is available to use"
```

I know what I am doing wrong but I can't find a way to fix it so it works as described above.  How do I edit the loop to get desired results?

Thanks
Zohaib

Comment: So if the chosen vlan already exists, you want to _append_ "1" (string concatenation) to the vlan, and if that value already exists, then you want to _increment_ by 1 (numeric) until it doesn't?

Comment: Your code does not do what you say, specifically, this part: `... The script will look at vlan table and determine if vlan 10 is available, if it is then it succeeds. If not, the first iteration it will append 1 to 10  ...`. In your code, you append even if `vlan` is in `vlan_list`.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar `vlan_list` contains vlans that already exist, i.e. are __not__ available to be chosen.

Comment: Yes, it will only do the append and increments if vlan exists in vlan_list, otherwise it print vlan is available to use.  Sorry not good explanation on my part. John is absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to append "1" once, so that part shouldn't be in a loop.

```
if vlan in vlan_list:
    print "Vlan " + vlan + " is already in use, creating new vlan ..."
    vlan = vlan + "1"
    print "Vlan chosen is: " + vlan
    while vlan in vlan_list:
        print "Vlan " + vlan + " is already in use, creating new vlan ..."
        vlan = str(int(vlan) + 1)
        print "Vlan chosen is: " + vlan
```

Comment: This one works great as well... Thanks.  Now I have to decide if I choose this or the other solution  :)

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```
while vlan in vlan_list:
    print "Vlan " + vlan + " is already in use, creating new vlan ..."
    initial = initial + 1
    if initial <= 1:
        str_initial = str(initial)
        vlan = vlan  + str_initial
    else:
        vlan = str(int(vlan) + 1)
    print "Vlan chosen is: " + vlan
```

The problem is that the first time you should append the number, the other times you shouldn't. By adding the check it should work, since initial is only one the first time it passes through.

**With values over 9 (2 digits) it 'overflows' into the rest of the number!** What is the desired behaviour after that?

Comment: It works for vlan 10 and I will test different #s.  I am not sure what you mean by values over 9.  Can you give me an example vlan # that it wouldn't work with?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear on that. If there are already 10 different vlan_10 (101, 102, 103, ..., 109), the new vlan will become 110. I do not know if that is desired behaviour.

Comment: Yes it is.  It appends 1 the first iteration and then it should start increment like usual. I don't believe it will ever do more than 5-10 iteration since we don't have many vlans on switches.  I will test a bit more but I think thats a solid solution .. :)  Thanks!!